# Remover um item de um List<>

Tags: c#, sql-server

Bem, tenho um método que faço consultas no meu banco e comparo com um `List<Carros>`. Minha intenção é, a cada item que contenha tanto na minha consulta, quando no meu `List<Carros>`, eu removo o item do meu `List<Carros>`.

```
 private List<Carros> GetCarros(long userId, List<Carros> list)
 {
     var retornaCarros = _CarrosRepository.GetCarrosType(CarrosType.ROSA.Value, userId);

     if (retornaCarros.Count() > 0)
     {
         foreach (var itemCarros in retornaCarros)
         {
            // AQUI REMOVER O ITEM QUE TENHA NO MEU LIST<>
         }
     }

     return new List<Carros>();
 }
```

Comment: Uma nota, verificar se o resultado tem elementos e redundante neste caso dado que a iteração não acontece caso não haja elementos (e esta a forcar a colecção a ser avaliada duas vezes).

Comment: @Omni Bem observado.

Answer (score 6):

Pode usar o método [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)(`System.Linq`) para resolver o problema:

```
private IEnumerable<Carros> GetCarros(long userId, List<Carros> list)
{
    var retornaCarros = _CarrosRepository.GetCarrosType(CarrosType.ROSA.Value, userId);
    return list.Except(retornaCarros);
}
```

O método `Except` devolve uma lista com os elementos da primeira lista (no seu caso, `list`) que não aparecem na segunda lista (`retornaCarros`).

(Se quiser retornar uma `List<Carros>` em vez de `IEnumerable<Carros>` chame o método `.ToList()` (return `list.Except(retornaCarros).ToList()`) e mude a assinatura do método.

[(Veja um exemplo no DotNetFiddle.)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fd1bUp)

**EDIT (Relativemente ao comentário do dcastro):**

Efectivamente no caso da sua classe `Carros` é necessário que esta faca *override* dos métodos `.GetHashCode()` e `.Equals(object obj)` para que o `.Except()` seja efectuado com sucesso.

No entanto, nem sempre e possível fazer esses *overrides*. Assim, uma forma de resolver o problema é criar uma classe que implemente `IEqualityComparer<Carros>`. Uma instância desta classe pode ser passada para o `.Except()`, que por sua vez vai utilizá-la para fazer a comparação (ao invés de usar os métodos da classe base `object`).

Uma possível implementação (assumindo que existe uma propriedade `UniqueId` na classe `Carros`):

```
public class CarrosComparer: IEqualityComparer<Carros>
{
    public int GetHashCode(Carros carro)
    {
        return carro.UniqueId;
    }

    public bool Equals(Carros carro1, Carros carro2)
    {
        return carro1.UniqueId == carro2.UniqueId;
    }
}
```

Depois pode fazer o seguinte:

```
private IEnumerable<Carros> GetCarros(long userId, List<Carros> list)
{
    var retornaCarros = _CarrosRepository.GetCarrosType(CarrosType.ROSA.Value, userId);
    return list.Except(retornaCarros, new CarrosComparer());
}
```

[(Veja um exemplo no DotNetFiddle.)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a46wev)

**Uma nota interessante sobre a forma como o `IEqualityComparer` é utilizado:**

O método `.Equals()` só é invocado se os *hash codes* de ambas as instâncias forem iguais. Pode verificar esta situação mudando `.GetHashCode()` no *fiddle* acima.

Comment: Precisas de chamar `ToList` para avaliar o `IEnumerable`, ou mudar o tipo de retorno. By the way, existe um efeito secundário que é importante mencionar: `Except` é uma operação de *sets* (conjuntos) e, portanto, elimina duplicados.

Comment: (E a resposta assume que o tipo `Carro` implementa correctamente os métodos `Equals` e `GetHashCode`)

Answer (score 4):

Use o método [Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) da classe `List<T>`

```
private List<Carros> GetCarros(long userId, List<Carros> list)
{
    var retornaCarros = _CarrosRepository.GetCarrosType(CarrosType.ROSA.Value, userId);

    // Como muito bem disse o Omni o if não é necessário
    //if (retornaCarros .Count() > 0)
    //{
        foreach (var itemCarros in retornaCarros )
        {
           list.Remove(itemCarros);
        }
    //}

    return list;
}
```

**Nota:** Parto do principio que `retornaCarros` é do tipo `List<Carros>`.

**EDIT**

Tal como disse o dcastro no cometário à resposta do Omni, também o método *Remove* para que funcione corretamente sobre *reference types*, eles terão de implementar a interface [IEquatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Supondo que `Carros` é uma entidade ela terá um campo ID, assim sendo é fácil implementar a interface:

```
public class Carros : IEquatable<Carros>
{

    //Suas Propriedades
    //Seus Métodos

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        Carros objAsCarros = obj as Carros;
        if (objAsCarros == null) return false;
        else return Equals(objAsCarros);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID;
    }

    public bool Equals(Carros other)
    {
        if(other == null)return false;
        return ID.Equals(other.ID);
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Deverá substituir `ID` pelo nome da propriedade de `Carros` que a torna única.